# To search the data with multiple bit values in MS sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am facing a problem in a procedure with bit variable, in this procedure i want to search a data  which shows result on the basis of passed value, either 0 or 1, otherwise if null is passed in bit variable the whole table is selected in sql i.e all the values with 0 or 1 is selected.

My procedure is as follows:

```
ALTER PROC SearchAppointmets
    @fromTime date,
    @toTime date,
    @cancel bit,
    @rescheduled bit,
    @approve bit
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT AppointmentId, FirstName, LastName, Phone, EmailId, Message, date, Time,
            AddressId, ApproveStatus, canceled, uploadDate, CancellationMessage,
            CancelStatus, RescheduleStatus, CancelRequestDate
       FROM AppointmetsData
      WHERE ((@fromTime = '' AND @toTime = '') OR (date BETWEEN @fromTime AND @toTime))
        AND (@cancel = '' OR (canceled =@cancel))
        AND (@rescheduled = '' OR (RescheduleStatus = @rescheduled ))
        AND (@approve = '' OR (approvestatus=@approve))
END
```

In this, i get correct result if the value passed is null or 1, But when i pass 0 as value it take it as null and result same data as of null value.

Comment: Your syntax looks like SQL Server.  Why does the question have the mysql tag?

Comment: Provide sample data. Getting the same result for NULL and 0 does not mean it's wrong. Maybe you just don't have any rows which are set to 0. In that case, 0 will of course return the same as NULL because the conditions evaluate to false in both cases.

Comment: Sir, I have data with both 0 and 1 values.. So, there is no chance for that issue..

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is not the same as an empty string (except in Oracle).  So you need to phrase your logic as:

```
where
((@fromTime is null and @toTime is null) or (date between @fromTime and @toTime))
and (@cancel is null or (canceled =@cancel))
and (@rescheduled is null or (RescheduleStatus = @rescheduled ))
and (@approve is null or (approvestatus=@approve))
```

Comment: Sir, I have already tried it as per your suggestion i.e replacing **= ''** with **Is Null** but it doesn't reflected any positive change in results...

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
where 
 ((@fromTime = '' and @toTime = '') or (date between @fromTime and @toTime))
and
((@approve=0) and approvestatus=@approve)or((@approve=1) and approvestatus=@approve)or((@approve is null) and approvestatus in(0,1))
option(recompile)

than execute 
execute SearchAppointmets1 '','',true
execute SearchAppointmets1 '','',false
execute SearchAppointmets1 '','',null
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build a dynamic query to only add `WHERE` clause filters as needed:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = 'SELECT AppointmentId, FirstName, LastName, Phone, EmailId, Message, date,
                   Time, AddressId, ApproveStatus, canceled, uploadDate,
                   CancellationMessage, CancelStatus, RescheduleStatus,
                   CancelRequestDate
              FROM AppointmetsData
             WHERE 1 = 1'

IF (@FromTime IS NOT NULL AND @ToTime IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + ' AND [date] BETWEEN ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @FromTime, 127) + '''
         AND ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @ToTime, 127) + ''''
END

IF (@cancel IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + ' AND CancelStatus = ' + CAST(@cancel AS VARCHAR(5))
END

IF (@rescheduled IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + ' AND RescheduleStatus = ' + CAST(@rescheduled AS VARCHAR(5))
END

IF (@approve IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + ' AND ApproveStatus = ' + CAST(@approve AS VARCHAR(5))
END


EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Note: I've added `WHERE 1 = 1` so that all following filters are simply `AND {some filter condition}`; this is just to make things simpler in the SQL.

With the above, if one of the variables is `NULL` the filter is not added to the final query that is executed in the last line (`EXEC sp_executesql @sql;`).